# undefined reference to function, ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, function, netbeans, reference, undefined

I keep getting these errors when trying to compile, All the solutions i have looked up are telling me its the linker thats the problem but i cannot find a way to fix it, I created a smaller program to try and work out the bug this is what i have.

main.c

```
#include "lib/navigation.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

location newLocation;
double a;
int main(void) {

newLocation.lat=51.2;
newLocation.lng=-5;

 a=great_circle(newLocation,newLocation);
 printf("%f", a);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

navigation.h

```
#ifndef NAVIGATION_H
#define NAVIGATION_H

typedef struct {
double lat;
double lng;
} location;

double great_circle(location location_1, location location_2);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* NAVIGATION_H */
```

I'm trying to use the great_circle function which i have linked using netBeans to the Navigation.a file but this is the error i get when compiling:

```
gcc     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/ship_project build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o lib/libnavigation_32bit.a -lm
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Random Guy A/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Ship Project/main.c:19: undefined reference to `great_circle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me? thank you in advance.

Comment: Clearly `great_circle` is not implemented and/or not linked with your program.

Comment: You need 2 things - 1 is to implement the great_circle in navigation.c. The second is to build navigation.o and hand it out to gcc when it compiles main. If you start using libraries, you should also start using makefiles.

Comment: Yes it isnt linked properly, I just need to know how to fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't `lib/libnavigation_32bit.a` be `-Llib -lnavigation_32bit`?

Comment: I don't know :-( that output is from the Netbeans compiler I didnt type it in manually, oh yeah im using windows too...

Comment: Check for compiler options in your IDE, you can manually specify, to the compiler, the options pointed out by @alk .